# How to apply sum to multiple columns in single query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using laravel and I have to get sum of the 3 columns separately not together.

for e.g

this is my table

```
 Maths - Science - english
   10     20        10
   15     25        30
```

and I'm using query like this

```
$math = Table::condition->sum('Maths');
$science= Table::condition->sum('Science ');
$english= Table::condition->sum('english');
```

I'm using 3 queries to get the result. How can I do this in a single query in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

try `selectRaw()` ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods

```php
Table::selectRaw('sum(Maths) as total_math,sum(Science) as total_science,sum(english) as total_english')->get();
```

Comment: is there any option without using selectRaw ?

Comment: @Invincibleme i don't know may be yes , but i havn't seen yet  but laravel doc says so there should not be any issue